# RadComboBox load all item s on load and allow filtering on typing of text

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I use a RadComboBox And use the code exactly as same as mentioned at the site 
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/populatingwithdata/autocompletesql/defaultcs.aspx

I use the code for "Server side" on the page mentioned in the above link.

However i am able to populate the values the first time the page is loaded but when i type in text it does not refine .Am i missing out on something ?

Regards,
Francis P.

Answer (score 2):

Have you done the properties like this.

```
EnableLoadOnDemand="True"
ShowMoreResultsBox="true"
EnableVirtualScrolling="true"
```

And for the filtering you need to implement item requested event.

```
OnItemsRequested="RadComboBox1_ItemsRequested"

And server method like this.

 protected void RadComboBox1_ItemsRequested(object sender, RadComboBoxItemsRequestedEventArgs e)
        {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For filtering you can just set markfirstmatch="true"